# MySQL transaction query help

Tags: sql, mysql, transactions, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

This problem is baffling me:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO sub_users(user_id, email) 
SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email='someemail@email.com', '$email';
COMMIT;
```

Normally, I have multiple statements in that transactions, but I've removed those for clarity.

I get this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 'test@email.com'' at line 1
```

**I'm using MySQL version 5.1.36**

Comment: I might have to start a new post as this one seems to be confusing everyone. I simply want to select ONE value from the users table, then insert that and the user defined value of $email into the table sub_users.

Comment: No need for a new post; please re-read replies carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems with your statement:

1. You're not selecting email to insert (only id)
2. You're using '=' instead of **IN** clause.

Should be something like:

```
INSERT INTO sub_users(user_id, email)
 SELECT user_id, email FROM users
  WHERE email IN ('someemail@email.com', 'test@email.com');
```

instead.

**Update** (based on comment)

```
INSERT INTO sub_users(user_id, email)
 SELECT user_id, 'test@email.com' FROM users
  WHERE email = 'someemail@email.com';
```

Comment: The email I want to insert is in the table I'm selecting from.

Comment: You're selecting from `users`. The above query will select all records from `users` whose `email` field is 'someemail@email.com' or 'test@email.com' and insert those records into `sub_users`. If you want to do something else, please clarify your question

Comment: Ok, I want to take the user_id of the user with email someemail@email.com, then insert that into the sub_users table along with a new email (test@email.com). So test@email.com will come from a php variable, not the database.

Comment: I see. You need to specify your new email as constant value (or a parameter you're going to bind) in select clause. I've updated my answer above with a sample select.

Comment: test@email.com should not come from any mysql table. It will be defined by the user so it will be PHP variable.

Comment: It's **NOT** coming from any mysql table. How are you creating the insert / select statement above in PHP? By concatenating the strings? So just replace `test@email.com` with your PHP variable - insert it into query the same way you're inserting `someemail@email.com`

Comment: sorry, i assumed that test@email.com was part of the select statement; that's what it looks like. I tested it out and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have at least two errors that I can see:

1. You are trying to insert two columns worth of data (`user_id` and `email`) but only selecting one column (`user_id`) from the second half of `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`. You must select the same number of columns as you are trying to insert, and order matters.
2. You have a syntax error in the predicate of your `SELECT`. I think you want to use:

   `WHERE email IN ('email1@foo.com', 'email2@bar.com')`

or its equivalent:

```
WHERE email = 'email1@foo.com'
   OR email = 'email2@bar.com'
```

Comment: But what if the second value I want to insert is not to come from the select. What do I do then?

Comment: I only need the user_id from the users table.

Comment: @Chad, you can do `INSERT INTO sub_users (user_id, email) SELECT user_id, 'some constant' FROM ...`. `'some constant'` can also be a function or another field from the table you're selecting from.

Comment: no, the email will not come from any table, it will be from a PHP variable.

Comment: I've reposted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622916/simple-mysql-query-question

Comment: OK, so set the `'some constant'` from PHP. `INSERT INTO sub_users (user_id, email) SELECT user_id, '$myVarSqlEscaped' FROM ...`