# Simple MySQL query question

Tags: php, mysql

How would I do this (the part in square brackets):

```
$name = 'Bob';

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table(field1,field2) 
[ select value of field1 from another table ], '$name'");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SQL part of it might look like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2) SELECT field1, 'Bob' FROM table2 WHERE ...
```

Dynamically constructing that in PHP is a simple exercise I leave up to the reader :)